# problem with call image from azure blob storage with cognitive services

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to use an azure cognitive service, which throws me an error:

*"ValueError: Content type could not be auto-detected because the stream was not readable/seekable. Please pass the content_type keyword argument."*

My code is the following:

```
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import FormRecognizerClient

endpoint = "https://example.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"
key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx820"

read_image_url = 'https://storage-example.blob.core.windows.net/ocr-demo/inputs/IMG_1618.jpg?sp=r&st=2022-06-30xxxxxx31Z&se=2023-0xxxxxx:31Z&spr=https&sv=xxxxx08&sr=b&sig=6xxxxxxxx'

form_recognizer_client = FormRecognizerClient(
   endpoint=endpoint, credential=AzureKeyCredential(key)
)
```

I don't understand why that returns me since I grant the KEY directly from the service and the image as well.

Can you give me any clue please what could be my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: Hi @Gonza, can you share the rest of your code example, specifically where `read_image_url` is getting passed? If passing a URL input, make sure you are using the "xxx_from_url" variant of the client method (e.g. begin_recognize_content_from_url)

Answer (score 0):

To call image from the blob storage using cognitive services, we can implement **Cognitive Search** procedure. We need to implement **Blob Indexer.** By default we can't see implementation of **indexer** on **images**. But all the images will be embedded into **.MSG** file and extract the attachments in the file.

That extraction will return the **normalized_images** fields. Even though the blob contain images, that will be ignored until the we perform [AI enrichment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-concept-intro).

Import the `data wizard` like mentioned in the following image.

[image]

Checkout the complete **indexer** procedure from [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-blob-storage-integration)